# Return string value to array from loop (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

Not sure if that's the term I should use for it but what I'm trying to do is add `len` amount of characters to an array, then output that to a `.txt`. I have the generation done to my satisfaction but I'm not sure how to pack the strings into an array. Right now it just spits out all the strings into the console because of the `puts` statement, just to make sure it works.

```
#Password list generator by Nightc||ed, ©2015
norm = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
caps = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
puts "How many passwords would you like to generate?"
num = gets.to_i
system "cls"
puts "Password length (1-x):"
len = gets.to_i
system "cls"
puts """
Which characters would you like to use?
[1] a-z, 0-9
[2] A-Z, 0-9
[3] a-z, A-Z, 0-9
"""
arr = []
type = gets.chomp
if type == "1"
    arr = [norm,nums]
elsif type == "2"
    arr = [caps,nums]
elsif type == "3"
    arr = [norm,caps,nums]
else
    exit
end
num.times do |pass|
    len.times do |char|
        arr2 = arr.to_a.sample
        char = arr2.to_a.sample
        puts char
    end
end
sleep
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify your life by replacing the `if...` and below with the following:

```
case type
  when "1"
    arr = [norm,nums].flatten
  when "2"
    arr = [caps,nums].flatten
  when "3"
    arr = [norm,caps,nums].flatten
  else
    exit
end
passwd_set = []
num.times { passwd_set << arr.sample(len).join }
p passwd_set
```

I find `case` statements easier to read, and more easily extended.  Flattening the arrays makes it so `sample` can directly produce the desired number of characters/symbols, and those can be `join`ed to produce a string which can be appended to your `passwd_set` array.

Answer (score 1):

here your code simplified

```
#Password list generator by Nightc||ed, ©2015
norm = [*"a".."z"]
caps = [*"A".."Z"]
nums = [*0..9]
num, len, type = [
   "How many passwords would you like to generate?",
   "Password length (1-x):",
   "Which characters would you like to use?
    [1] a-z, 0-9
    [2] A-Z, 0-9
    [3] a-z, A-Z, 0-9"].map do |msg|
     puts msg
     gets.to_i
   end

arr = case type
      when 1 then
        norm + nums
      when 2 then
        caps + nums
      when 3 then
        norm + caps + nums
      else
        exit
      end

passwords = num.times.map { arr.sample(len).join }
puts passwords.inspect
sleep
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to an array using the [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) method.  For example:

```
arr = []
3.times do |el|
  arr << el
end
arr.inspect #=> [0, 1, 2]
```

Another option would be the [`push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-push) method:

```
arr = []
(0..2).each { |el| arr.push(el)}
```

Comment: that helps considerably but I need to export to `num` amount of arrays